# How to pack a struct tightly on Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, struct, padding

I'm trying to create a packed struct which represents a header of a specific data packet. Because of this, it must not have any padding to match the size given in the specification. However, on Windows, it will have a 1 Byte padding after the last field, no matter how I tell the compiler to tightly pack the structure.

I have tried this code on Compiler Explorer and on most of the platforms I get the result I wanted, except for MSVC. I also tried on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) with GCC which again gives me a proper result. I only got padding issues on Windows.

The simplified version of the stucture looks like this:

```cpp
typedef struct
{
    unsigned a : 10;
    unsigned b : 1;
    unsigned c : 5;
    unsigned d : 8;
} __attribute__((packed)) A;
```

Using MSVC:

```cpp
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    unsigned a : 10;
    unsigned b : 1;
    unsigned c : 5;
    unsigned d : 8;
} A;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

In case of MSVC I also tried to add the /Zp1 compiler parameter to default to 1 Byte alignment.

I expect the size of the structure to be 3 Bytes. On Linux with gcc or clang it's okay, but on Windows with MinGW GCC or MSVC, the size is always 4 Bytes.

Comment: `unsigned int /* assumes 24+ bits */ A; unsigned a = A & 0x3ff; unsigned b = (A && 0x400) >> 10; ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the types to this:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short a : 10;
    unsigned short b : 1;
    unsigned short c : 5;
    unsigned char d : 8;
} A;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Then it does come out as 3 bytes.

You could also emulate the bitfields manually, to minimize such surprises.

Comment: I assume it works because the first 3 fields fit in 16 bits, the last fits in 8, and since it doesn't use the 4 byte unsigned type for all of them, there is no need to add the extra byte after the last field. Am I right?